# call remove item event in autocomplete multiselect PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, autocomplete

How can call remove item event inautocomplete multiselect PrimeFaces??

I want when remove item update **lstSelectedDays**.

I try use **change event** but not working.

I did a lot of searching but I did not find a solution!

```
 <p:autoComplete id="ClassSeessionDays" multiple="true" value="#{classManage.lstSelectedDays}"
              completeMethod="#{weekDaysRequestBean.getDays}" dropdown="true"
              var="day" itemLabel="#{day.name}" itemValue="#{day}" converter="weekDaysConverter" 
              disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
              forceSelection="true">

           <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="pnlClassSession" update="pnlClassSession" global="false" partialSubmit="true"/>
           <p:ajax event="change"   update="pnlClassSession" global="false" partialSubmit="true"/>

           <f:attribute name="lstSelectedDays" value="#{classManage.lstSelectedDays}" />
           <p:column >
                  <h:outputText value="#{day.name}" />
           </p:column>                                                       
  </p:autoComplete>
```

How can update **lstSelectedDays** after remove a item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use itemUnselect ajax event to capture unselect event.

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiice...tanks